# What is a "French bed room" in German hotel terminology?

Tags: germany, hotels

I have booked a hotel room in Germany.

On the reservation confirmation, it says:

> Room category: 1 × French bed room non-smoking

What is a *French bed room*?

Comment: Does it say "French bedroom" anywhere on your confirmation, or only "French bed"?  (I'd read the confirmation as "Room with a French bed", not "French bedroom".)  Otherwise, you might want to update the title of your question.

Comment: @npl It does say "French bed room".  My mind had turned it into "French bedroom".

Comment: "French bed" is a common term in German for a 140x200 (cm) bed.  "French bedroom", on the other side, isn't a common term AFAIK.  But I agree it is misleading if you don't know the term "French bed".

Comment: Un dortoir Français!

Comment: @npl: French bedroom exists, too, I've seen that. It's an euphemism for a slightly cheaper, but inferior room, which _also_ has a "French" bed in the room.

Comment: Just for completeness, French people would not understand what this means. The normal "lit double", qualified as "lit en 140" or "lit en 160" is a single-mattress bed, whereas the "lit simple" is normally 80 or 90 cm wide. Having two separate "lits simples juxtaposables" is also normal, if not as frequent, especially in hotel or guest rooms where it may be desired to pull them apart. I'm far from an expert, but the only times I have seen distinct mattresses on the same frame have been for special beds where motors can adjust the elevation.

Comment: @npl or an extremely small room where it's almost impossible to even walk around in because there's simply no space left after they put in a bed. Most extreme example I've seen had a television bolted to the wall and the bathroom door removed because it couldn't swing open, to get into the shower you had to sit on the toilet, swing around, and stand up again.

Comment: I'm Germand and I have never heard of a 'French bed' - must be a regional thing.

Comment: I have never heard of this, ever.  Totally weird.  They probably mean a large, one-piece mattress (I'd call it "USA style") rather than the more typical "split" German double mattress.  **BUT** it could mean simply a "smaller" double bed.  I don't know.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

German double beds are usually equipped with two mattresses. A 'French bed' (französisches Bett), on the other hand, is a bed wide enough for two persons, but equipped only with *one* mattress.

They are usually narrower than regular double beds, the most common width is 140cm, but not necessarily. If you look into bed shops with a wider selection of products, you can get [120, 140, 160 and 180cm-wide French beds](https://www.slewo.com/ratgeber/wissenswertes/franzoesisches-bett.html):

> Die Breiten variieren von 1,20 bis 1,80 m.

The name allegedly comes from the 'cosier' way French people tend to spend their night. German partners obviously rather stick to 'mine and thine' sides of the bed, with a clear separation line for extra protection.

Comment: Having slept for years in actual French-style beds I can categorically state that they are *not* cosier than proper German beds. ;-) Heinrich Heine [famously deplores](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/-383/8) the low quality of French-style bedding.

Comment: Indeed, having recently moved to Germany we (my wife and I) found that when buying a bed, getting a single mattress was not straightforward, and the default option in most of the places we looked were two separate mattresses.

Comment: Here in the UK, some hotels offering double beds (beds for two sleeping together) often use the German style.  Not because for comfort, it's because they can easily separate the beds and use the room as a "twin" room instead (two separated single beds).  I don't know whether German hotels do this or not.  Doing this in the UK (German style) is seen as being a bit cheap by English people, who are used to the French style of double beds.

Comment: 120 and 140 are technically single person beds, 160 and up are dual beds with single mattresses.

Comment: @jwenting No. Not even the Germans have a strict and technical definition of the distinction between single and double beds based on the width. If we look at the 'common sizes' table in the Wikipedia article, beds up to 120cm are *usually* considered single bed, while beds 140cm wide or wider are *usually* considered double beds. If you however look at which bed sizes are commonly available to buy, a single bed will rarely be wider than 90cm and a double bed rarely narrower than 140cm.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Matter of opinion. I despise soft beds despite being German, the harder, the better and in fact I have a 140cm french bed with a hard spring mattress. Absolutely no back pain problems (but that could also be by going regularly to traditional thai massage).

Comment: @ThorstenS. I agree about hard mattresses. However, I wasn’t talking about mattresses, I (and Heine, too, at least in part) was talking about *duvets* (= “Federbetten”). French beds traditionally (and often still to this day) don’t have duvets, only bed covers, tucked into the end of the bed (?!?!?), with a scratchy comforter haphazardly thrown on top. 

Comment: @KonradRudolph Now I am outed as ignoramus, I needed to look it up how the french bed looks like. During our stay in the Cévennes we stayed in the tent and using the sleeping bag *so I did not know that the french bed uses no soft, cosy blanket, but a tied-down canvas cover*. **Sorry**.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo that's how these beds are sold when you go to a furniture store. Might not be a legal definition, but it's what's used in practice

Comment: @jwenting Depends very much on where you are. Here in Scandinavia, for example, a 140 bed (which would generally be called queen-size here) would not generally be marketed as a single bed in a furniture store, but as a double bed.

Comment: @jwenting.  In the UK a "standard double" is 137cm, a "small double" is 122cm.  And that is absolutely how they will be described in furniture stores.  https://www.bedtimesuperstores.co.uk/blog/post/uk-standard-bed-sizes-and-dimensions/

Comment: @Fattie Why do you believe that the answer from Jeremy is correct and I am wrong? I have linked to a furniture shop, where they explain what a French bed is and you can find similar descriptions from other furniture shops. Are they all wrong?

Comment: that would seem to do it, @Tor-EinarJarnbjo  :)  cheers ..

Comment: @Snow I've yet to see a UK hotel offering a double bed with two mattresses. One mattress (and one sheet!) seems to be very much the standard. Unfortunately, as I prefer the German style. When travelling with a friend to the UK I will not book a hotel unless they explicitely state they have twin rooms.

Answer (score 25):

Some German hotels use this term to refer to a room with a double bed of standard size - 140cm wide. Essentially, the bed sleeps 2 and many people have this size in their homes, but people used to queen- or king-sized beds may find the bed small. It doesn't imply a particular style of decor or arrangement of bedding.

Comment: To back this up: https://www.conrad-hotel.de/en/room/standard-room-french-bed/

Comment: Why is it called a "French" bed? Do the French just like smaller beds?

Comment: @AzorAhai: Maybe to make the pill easier to swallow => it's not "small", it's fashionable!

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree on this one. German double beds are usually equipped with two mattresses and I know the term "French bed" for a double bed with *one* mattress as opposed to the usual two. Surely, French beds are usually a bit narrower than 'regular' double beds, but they are not necessarily bound to a 140cm width. This German retailer sells French beds both 140cm and 160cm wide: https://www.bettenriese.de/matratzen-ratgeber/franzoesisches-bett/

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo what is "regular" is completely subjective.

Comment: "Why is it called a "French" bed?"  it's like asking "why is it called Canadian bacon" or "Why is it called driving Anglais?" or "Why is it called a dutch oven"?  Obviously, these odd phrases just happen over time, it's no mystery.

Comment: @Fattie, also why do some countries call "Italian salad" a Russian recipe invented by a French cook?

Comment: Heh didn't know that one, @AndreaLazzarotto, thanks  :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue arises from sloppy punctuation.

Hotel and motel rooms are commonly described by the size and number of beds contained. Thus, one sees "queen bed room" and "king bed room" and so on.

The OP's room contains one French bed, and thus is a "French bed room."

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't really help those of who have never heard of a "French bed". Other answers at least attempt to give a useful definition (even if there is some disagreement).

Comment: @IMSoP, *I'd* never heard of a French bed, either. I thought it'd be helpful for others to know that bed type/number are often used as a compound adjective to describe hotel rooms.

Answer (score 0):

In hotels, "french bed" usually denotes pretty narrow double bed (meant for TWO persons). It can be as narrow as 140 centimeters and will almost always come with shared duvet. My personal opinion is, that these beds are definitely not meant for sleeping, but for other activities :).

The experience of different people may vary, but I would suggest avoiding this if you need decent space to sleep well. And, of course, such bed is very much not suited for sharing with anyone else except people you are really intimate with.

On the other hand, for a single use, these beds are quite ok.

Comment: If you are used to wider beds, to separate duvets and so on, you might find it a bit less nice. But not all are happy with separation in bed, some prefer a single mattress and a single duvet, even when just sleeping side by side.